# How to programmatically submit a filled form and scrape the resulting page?

Tags: java, javascript, forms, post, screen-scraping

I want to retrieve a set of results, which consist of all results produced by (looping) all the options of one of the request-form fields.

I'm using Java language, and HtmlUnit API.

I have managed to do this looping form-fill using the URL to 'fill' the field's variables (I don't know if its the best method, and actually am quite worried it's one of the worst...But it's the one i could do with the knowledge i have).

But i'm having problems figuring out how to make the program submit the form in order to reach the result page, and on how to download (**scrape**) that page before moving to the next.

NOTES:

-If you have a better way of filling the 'request-form', that is welcome as well.

---

**UPDATE:**

This solves the issues when using HtmlUnit API (thank you, [touti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9983306/1253136)):

```
HtmlPage resultado = pageNow.getElementByName("buscar").click();
System.out.println(resultado.asText());
```

A better way than loading both the request and response pages is still hugely welcome tough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simulate using Jquery the click on your submit input like this
`$("#submit_id").trigger("click");`

Comment: Yes, thank you...I had forgotten to tell what API i was using [fixed]...and was failing to figure out the click() thing...